# combine procedure and cursor in sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, procedure

newbie here.

I am trying to do self-learning about SQL.
Right now, I am having a problem in combining procedure and cursor.

Hereby the case

### The Case

> Create procedure named ‘sp4’ that receive StaffName from user’s input
>   to display StaffName and StaffPosition for every staff which name
>   contains the word that has been inputted by user.
>   (create procedure, declare cursor, like)

Hereby the code that I have tried it

### My Code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp4 (@name VARCHAR(100))
AS
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR
SCROLL
FOR 
    SELECT StaffName, StaffPosition
    FROM MsStaff
    OPEN cur2
    DECLARE @pointer AS VARCHAR(100)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @pointer
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT StaffName, StaffPosition
        FROM MsStaff
        WHERE @pointer = @name
        AND StaffName LIKE '%' + @pointer + '%'

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @name
    END
    CLOSE cur2
    DEALLOCATE cur2
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement for the cursor indicates `SELECT StaffName, StaffPosition` but your `FETCH` statements don't match that (or each other).

The `FETCH` is going to load the data from the cursor into your memory variables.  So you need to supply one variable for each column indicated in the `SELECT`. For example, if you have

```
DECLARE @staffName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @staffPosition VARCHAR(100)
```

then you can replace **both** of your fetches with:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @staffName, @staffPosition
```